# Set Hint For Edittext In Android Or Xamarin

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I tried that Dynamic Hint For EditText  At Code Behind.At But Error Incomprehensible.
You can see the code later

EditText editTextAddres=FindViewById

Or In Java

EditText

```
editTextAddres=FindViewById<EditText(Resource.Id.entereventeditTextAddres);
editTextAddres.hint="EnterCity";//Error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `EditText.Hint = "Your text"`

Comment: I had made a mistake to put the amount in TextView  mistake That's right

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText edtText;
edtText = findViewById(R.id.edtText);
edtText.setHint("Here goes your Hint");
```